# Parse a file - regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to export to a new txt file a list of URLs from another txt file.
The first txt file looks like this :

> http://pastebin.com/raw/10hvUbTi Emails: 631 Keywords: 0.0
>
> http://pastebin.com/raw/5f0bnCq9 Emails: 61 Keywords: 0.0

I am trying to create a list that will look like this:

> URL
>
> URL

I am not get anything as an output in pycharm

Can someone help please?

```
import re
import urllib2
filename = 'C:\\file.txt'
pattern = ('^\S*')
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        if pattern in line:
            print line
```

Comment: Show us the example input and the expected output (real examples).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw/10hvUbTi Emails: 631 Keywords: 0.0 http://pastebin.com/raw/c42wEasR Emails: 283 Hashes: 142 .                 i got nothing in output, it doesnt

Comment: Please edit the question and add the examples there. We would need example of the input (few lines) and expected output. And also on which lines it fails.

Comment: it doesnt fail :/. i just get : "Process finished with exit code 0"

Comment: Are the emails always separated with a pipe `|` ?

Comment: not every time, i just didnt succeed to export the urls from the first list, after that i will just save the page

Comment: Did you post a link to a list of user accounts and their passwords here?

Comment: Is [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/aM0wJ2/2) what you're after? `^(?P<email>[^|\n]+)`

Answer (score 1):

You could go for:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'^(?P<email>[^|\n]+)', re.MULTILINE)
with open("emails.txt") as f:
    raw_data = f.read()
    emails = [match.group('email') for match in rx.finditer(raw_data)]
    print emails
```

Obviously, `emails.txt` needs to be adjusted here.
See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/aM0wJ2/2).

Answer (score 0):

You did not use regular expression at all. You merely tested whether the raw string is in the line or not. To use regex,

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^\S*')
```

notice the `r` before pattern string there, it stands for raw string and is very important in regex.

To search for a `pattern` in a particular line, use

```
pattern.search(line)
```

It will return a `MatchObject` is a match is found, or `None` if nothing is found. More reference on python regular expression can be found in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: The pattern is meaningless unless captured.  "zero or more non-whitespace" will match every line.